# Gradle looking for aar in wrong project's lib folder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application made up of multiple projects.  One of those projects is an App project that just extends the Application object.

Inside the build.gradle for that app project, I add other projects as dependencies.

I've just created a new module to house an SDK (aar) I want to use.  I've also added it to my app project's build.gradle.

```
compile project(':newmodule-thesdk')
```

Inside the libs folder of newmodule-thesdk, I have added the aar file.  We'll call it thesdk.aar.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'thesdk-1.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

When I attempt to sync gradle, the sync fails because thesdk-1.0 does not exist in the libs folder of my **app** project.  Why is it looking for it there?  Why is it not just finding it in the newmodule-thesdk project?

Comment: In which build.gradle did you add the flatDir and the aar dependency?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti newmodule-thesdk

Comment: Why are you creating a module for housing an .aar ? Does it have another goal ?

Comment: @meynety The answer to that question is a bit complicated. I only want the SDK added to certain branches of my app project.  I have another project that houses the majority of the app's code, and I can't directly reference the SDK there because sometimes the app project will not include the SDK's project as a dependency.  I have a separate project for the SDK so I can house all my code referencing the SDK there.

Comment: did u solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears solving the problem required me to do the following in my App project's build.gradle.

```
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':newmodule-thesdk').file('libs')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and I just changed my xxx.aar to xxx-N.N.aar, in your case `thesdk.aar` to `thesdk-1.0.aar` and then it worked fine

Comment: This seems to not be the solution, but it's quite important to check the names

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your code this way

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['thesdk-1.0.aar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Keep in mind that the file should exist!

Answer (score 0):

u could do 2 approaches

1) As you already said it:

```
 repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':newmodule-thesdk').file('libs')
        }
    }
```

it can be done in this way

2)you can make a new gradle project with including the sdk and reference the old code project in it.

and then reference old project when u dont want to include the sdk and when you want to include the sdk reference the new gradle project